# How do I "Lock Camera to View" using Python?

Tags: python, 3d-view, camera

How do check the box labeled "Lock Camera to View" using Python?

There is a "lock_camera" property, but I don't know how to navigate to the object that has it to set it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This code checks the "Lock Camera to View" box:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
   if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
      for space in area.spaces:
         if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            space.lock_camera = True
```

Comment: Can also use `area.spaces.active` to get the space assoc. with the area.